# How does Linux md driver write data to SATA disk?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, raid

In [an Intel white paper](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/rst-linux-paper.pdf), it says:

> MD RAID in linux is a block driver that filters data between the Linux
>   File System driver, such as ext2 file system, and the low level hard
>   disk drivers, such as the AHCI driver and SAS driver.

In kernel code `drivers/md/md.c`, I only find this `file_operations`:

```
static const struct file_operations md_seq_fops = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .open           = md_seq_open,
    .read           = seq_read,
    .llseek         = seq_lseek,
    .release        = seq_release_private,
    .poll           = mdstat_poll,

};
```

md_fops has neither read nor write:

```
static const struct block_device_operations md_fops =
{
        .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
        .open           = md_open,
        .release        = md_release,
        .ioctl          = md_ioctl,
#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT
        .compat_ioctl   = md_compat_ioctl,
#endif
        .getgeo         = md_getgeo,
        .media_changed  = md_media_changed,
        .revalidate_disk= md_revalidate,
};
```

Is this the file_operations that MD driver performs open, read...? How does MD driver writes data? Use AHCI driver?

When a write syscall is called, what is the steps to write data?

sys_write -> vfs_write -> file->f_op->write or do_sync_write? The md_seq_fops has neither write nor aio_write

Answer (score 1):

The exact sequence of function calls will depend on various situations like whether I/O is direct or not, whether I/O is synchronous or asynchronous etc. Depending on these situations, at the end make_request() method of MD layer is called and this method is registered by MD layer itself at the time of RAID device creation by blk_queue_make_request() call as shown below in md.c file:

```
blk_queue_make_request(mddev->queue, md_make_request);
```

This md_make_request() function will internally calls make_request() method specific to that RAID device personality as shown below:

```
mddev->pers->make_request(mddev, bio);
```

You can find specific make_request() method in the list of RAID personality methods given in individual RAID files in source code, i.e., for raid0 personality, here is list of methods where make_request is initialized with raid0_make_request() in raid0.c file.

```
static struct md_personality raid0_personality=
{
         .name           = "raid0",
         .level          = 0,
         .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
         .make_request   = raid0_make_request,
         .run            = raid0_run,
         .free           = raid0_free,
         .status         = raid0_status,
         .size           = raid0_size,
         .takeover       = raid0_takeover,
         .quiesce        = raid0_quiesce,
         .congested      = raid0_congested,
};
```

This raid0_make_request() function will perform read or write on raid0 device.

Comment: Thank you very much. raid0_make_request -> generic_make_request -> q->make_request_fn(q, bio); right? How make_request_fn call AHCI driver to write data? (suppose sata drive connect to AHCI controller).

Comment: @siyuan: Yes. the sequence of function calls mentioned by you are correct. Regarding your second question, I have mostly worked on SCSI or SCSI related protocols. I am not sure about AHCI, but if its devices are registered as SCSI devices then scsi_request_fn -> scsi_dispatch_cmd and then queuecommand function pointer registered by your AHCI driver, which I am not sure but might be ata_scsi_queuecmd(). But if it is not going through SCSI path then you will need to find similar flow for AHCI driver.

Answer (score 0):

`struct file_operations` has many more members. Per C99, members not listed are initialized to `NULL` which means they're not specially implemented. That's normal for *filter* drivers; they replace only some operations.

Comment: Is MD raid a filter driver?